# Link css stylesheet with express.static problem

Tags: css, express, static

I'm just learning, so need some help with something.

When I try to load my html file on my local server it doesn't load my styles.css file.

I used the express.static on my "public" folder and modified the path of the styles.css in the html file. Some help would be great . Thanks.

The folder paths: css

> C:\Newsletter-Signup\public\css\styles.css

html file that i tryed to load with applied .css on it:

> C:\Newsletter-Signup\public\signup.html

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb69C.jpg)

this is my app.js file:

```
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html" );
});

app.listen("3000", function(){
  console.log("server started on port 3000");
});
```

and this is my link to styles.css that doesnt load:

```
< link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" >
```

Comment: I went through this issue again and post a generic solution below. Could you check that and let me know whether it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I am trying to present you a generic solution.So this may be helpful to fix the issue, which occurs during your code attempt.

When generating the express app project, I used the command `npm install -g express-generator` which recommended in Express Js official site. From that, I could easily create the folder structure for the express app.

[image]

---

### **.pug file format**

By default the generated express app only allows you to render `.pug` file format instead of `.html` file. Express-generator installs pug node module via `npm install pug -- save` while installs other required dependencies. After installs `pug` dependency you are allowed render `.pug` files locate in the root using localhost URL.

*app.js*

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('<pug file name>', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

Set your current directory as app root and run the command `npm start` from your terminal and visit the URL `http://localhost:<Port Name>/`

Then you can see the rendered `.pug` file.

---

### **Get support for .html file format**

Since Express Js supported `.pug` file format, you need to install `ejs` node module to get support for the `.html` format.

```
npm install ejs --save
```

Then need to update app.js file content as below

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('<html file name>', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

Now you will see, `.html` file is rendered properly.

---

### **Add a stylessheet to express app**

In `app.js` file, a directory path is already set for static files as shown below.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

It means that the `public` folder is set as static file directory.
So, when linking a stylesheet inside `head` tag, a relative path for stylesheet should be stated as `'stylesheets/style.css`.

```
<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/style.css">

</head>
```

Comment: I made it work both ways. I think was just a pathing problem, most likely. It loads the .css file with the html too. And I tried your way after. It was the first time I used the express generator so took me a bit to set it up, but I got it working. The only problem I had, was with this command : `npm install -g express-generator`. which didnt work for my node version, so I had to use this instead: `npx express-generator`.   Thank for your help and your time man. It's pretty hard learning only from online tutorials, without have someone to ask in real life. Cheers.